# Search (SearchView) Functionality for Listview

Tags: android, listview, searchview

i'm new to android. I'm just trying to make one simple search functionality for my app. My app consists one ListView and one SearchView for search. My ListView contents are listed from a String list using custom adapter which is extends BaseAdapter

Now, what i'm trying to do is, i want to search any records from ListView For example, if i've some records like

> aa abb ...

So, when i type some record name like a

The listview should listed the records which is started from a... I've referred something for this, from i got addTextChangedListener But, i don't know how to do this?

And, Can we do this same functionality with click of button

Has anyone having any idea on this? Thanks in advance

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView list ;
    private SearchView mSearchView;


    String [] a =   {"aa","abb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh","ii","jj","kk","ll"};
    String [] b =   {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                    list.clearTextFilter();
                } else {
                    Log.i("WSM",newText);
                    list.setFilterText(newText.toString());                 
                }
                return true;

            }
        });


        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, a, b));
        setupSearchView();
    }

     private void setupSearchView() {
            mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
            mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
        }

    class SingleRow{
        String  ssid;
        String  pass;

        public SingleRow (String ssid, String pass){
            this.ssid = ssid;
            this.pass = pass;
        }
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<SingleRow> myList ;
        Context c;


        public MyAdapter (Context c, String[] ssid, String [] pass){
            this.c = c;
            myList = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
            for (int i = 0; i<ssid.length; i++){
            myList.add(new SingleRow(ssid[i],pass[i]));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return myList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return myList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow, parent ,false);

            TextView TV_ssid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ssid);
            TextView TV_pass = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pass);

            SingleRow tmp = myList.get(position);
            TV_ssid.setText(tmp.ssid);
            TV_pass.setText(tmp.pass);

            return row;
        }

    }

}
```

**singlerow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.82"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:id="@+id/ssid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SSID: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PASS:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp"
            android:typeface="monospace"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For searching feature I recommend you this component:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidFilterableList

This allows you to filter whatever you want in an extremely easy way. Change filters dynamically etc.

You would have to modify your code in order to adapt it to this way of working... but I think it worths.

Take a look to the sample!!

I hope this would help you.